# standard dialable number format (c++ tapi)

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, telephony, tapi

I want to programatically make calls on a windows mobile device using standard c++ TAPI [lineMakeCall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894387.aspx) function. The phone number (null-terminated) must be in the "standard dialable number format".

There is a function [lineTranslateAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894539.aspx) which should make the conversion to the dialable format.

I am testing my application and if I use a nonformated string (ex: 0728000000, valid for my country), this number is dialed but not recognized (The dialing screen shows: Dialing: Unknown).

I cannot find much information about this standard format. Does anyone know something about this format, how it should look, or is it secret?

Help please,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the MSDN documentation page describing this format: [Dialable Addresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726017%28VS.85%29.aspx#dialable_addresses)

Comment: Thanks, I found it too a few minutes ago, and I was looking over it.